# Maintain col- settings but align height

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to work out how I make all columns align in height but maintain their column sizing, using bootstrap 5.

but for some reason, it overrides the column width. I'm trying to match the height of each but maintaining the `col-md-4` setting

So I have

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="row row-sm">
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4 d-flex">
    <div class="card custom-card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div>
          <h6>Genre:</h6>
          <h4><span class="fs-30 mr-2">{{project.category}}</span><span class="badge badge-success"></span></h4>
          <span class="text-muted">The style or category of the project.</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="card custom-card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div>
          <h6>Blockchain:</h6>
          <h4><span class="fs-30 mr-2">{{project.blockchain|upper}}</span><span class="badge badge-danger"></span></h4>
          <span class="text-muted">The system of recording information in a way that makes it difficult or impossible to change, hack, or cheat the system.</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
    <div class="card custom-card">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div>
          <h6>Type:</h6>
          <h4><span class="fs-30 mr-2">{{project.type|upper}}</span><span class="badge badge-success"></span></h4>
          <span class="text-muted">An informal classification used to categorise games</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried every variation of the flex and can't get this working, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else has this problem, I managed to get around it by ignoring the `flex` and just adding `h-100` to each of the cards and then setting an `mb-3` so it maintained the spacing.